# Date format from MSSQL to other

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, date-format, getdate

In MSSQL I have columns with date (only date, without time). It was saved with this function:

```
ROUND(CAST(GETDATE() AS REAL), 0, 1) + 36163 **(ex. 77009)**
```

How I can format this date (month etc.) with PHP, MySQL or even MSSQL.

For example: 77009 = 2011-11-01.

Comment: Is the column type actually `date`?

Comment: No. In MSSQL I have values like that: 77009 (INT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Sql Server
SELECT CONVERT(DateTime,XXX-36163)

eg.
SELECT @val = ROUND(CAST(GETDATE() AS REAL), 0, 1) + 36163
SELECT CONVERT(DateTime,@val-36163)

Comment: Thanks! Still looking for MySQL and PHP solution.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(YOUR_DATE_COLUMN);
```

Please refer to [the function in MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time)

Comment: It's no seconds - it's date without time.

Comment: aha, missed it. I'm not sure what number does CAST() change the date to

Comment: For example: 77009 = 2011-11-01

Comment: yes, but I am not clear what is the logic for converting 2011-11-01 to 77009. As it seems casting date to real automatically changes it to some number format