# PHP Julien date query

Tags: php, date

a database I am using has dates stored in integer format (where today = 79074 and appears to be Julien date + 36163). 
Do you know what the PHP code would be to recreate that in reverse from todays date?

I have found out its using an excel serialized date hence the wierd number 
I have found the function

```
        function ExcelToUnixTimestamp($dateValue = 0)
    {
        $excelBaseDate = 25567;

        // Perform conversion
        if ($dateValue >= 1) {
            $utcDays = $dateValue - $excelBaseDate;
            $returnValue = round($utcDays * 86400);
            if (($returnValue <= PHP_INT_MAX) && ($returnValue >= -PHP_INT_MAX)) {
                $returnValue = (integer) $returnValue;
                //echo $returnValue - 36163;
            }
        } else {
            $hours = round($dateValue * 24);
            $mins = round($dateValue * 1440) - round($hours * 60);
            $secs = round($dateValue * 86400) - round($hours * 3600) - round($mins * 60);
            $returnValue = (integer) gmmktime($hours, $mins, $secs);
            //echo $returnValue - 36163;
        }

        return $returnValue;
    }

    $weirdTimestamp = 79074;
    $unixTimestamp = ExcelToUnixTimestamp($weirdTimestamp - 36163);
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $unixTimestamp);
```

However I want to recreate this so that the date for today ( 79074 ) can be replaced each day with the new value ( excel serialized )

Can anyone help with this
Apologies was getting extremely stressed earlier

The question look like its similar to the issue here 
[Date format from MSSQL to other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483942/date-format-from-mssql-to-other/9484305)
Anyone able to shed some light on this

Comment: At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: It’s not that hard to type “php julian date” into Google ... so please make a _basic_ effort before asking here.

Comment: Yes i'm perfectly clear about that but HOW ELSE would you word that .. I dont have a clue how to find the answer to this hence there is no code otherwise I would have put it along with the question

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`gregoriantojd($month, $day, $year)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gregoriantojd.php) to get Julien date

```
gregoriantojd(date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'));
```

Comment: @ChrisYates Well, all I have done was `php Julian date` in Google... Are you too lazy?

Comment: @ChrisYates I rolled the question back to its original state. Instead of editing it to read as [*"question removed.... thanks for help"*](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44778526/2) you should have accepted the answer and mark the question as solved instead.

Comment: I have updated the code, am not trying to convert georgian to Julian apparently in an excel serialized date